# Detect font family in Sketch

Tags: fonts, sketch-app

Hi I'm a dev with a Photoshop background and I can't find a way to simply *click* on a Sketch design text element and display the font family used.

Could anyone help me on this one? Thank you very much

Comment: Hi. Weclome to GDSE.  Is the text element editable text, or outlines? If the latter, then the font name, size, and style are lost on conversion to outlines.  This goes for all vector image editors, not just sketch app.

Comment: Hi @Billy Kerr, thank you for your kind comment. Actually it's not editable you're right so I guess there's no way to figure that out

Comment: Please post this as an answer and I'll validate it

Comment: OK, I'll add it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your text elements are outlines rather than editable text, then the font name, size and style are lost on conversion to outlines. This goes for all vector image editors, and not just Sketch App.

Ultimately this means unless the text is still editable, then the font information is not available, nor can the data be retrieved. Obviously this doesn't solve your problem.

I guess you could take a screen capture of the text and run it through whatthefont or fontsquirrel matcherator, or other similar online font ID services.